# Is there a way to initialize a variable using a switch statement in JS as in Java?

Tags: javascript, variables, initialization, switch-statement

I'm trying to emulate this Java code in JavaScript:

```java
int my_val = 3;

int my_var = switch(my_val) {
    case 1 -> 2;
    case 3, 4 -> 5;
    default -> 0;
}
```

So far I've come up with:

```js
my_val = 3;

my_var = (() => {
    switch(my_val) {
        case 1: return 2;
        case 3: case 4: return 5;
        default: return 0;
    }
})();
```

Is there an easier/more proper way of doing it?

Comment: @khelwood - Bad tagging by the OP, this is JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: the second is the way to go. i would take `my_val` as paramter for the iife.

Comment: I was thinking [`do` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) might help (though they're only at Stage&nbsp;1), but working it through...no, not really. I mean, they get rid of the function, but it's still messy compared to an object or `Map`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a lookup table with an object or a `Map`:

```
const values = {
    1: 2,
    3: 5,
    4: 5,
};
const my_var = values[my_val] ?? 0;
```

Or with a `Map`:

You can do a lookup table with an object or a `Map`:

```
const values = new Map([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 5],
    [4, 5],
]);
const my_var = values.get(my_val) ?? 0;
```

The advantage to a `Map` over an object is that the keys don't get converted to strings.

Comment: Three-quarters through answering I realized wanting a `switch` expression probably doesn't make this unique enough that we don't have a dupetarget...

Comment: Unfortunately these only work when the values are actually simple constants like in OPs example. As soon as the different cases do anything more interesting, this approach gets significantly worse. Then the function approach is still better.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - Yes, I'm working on the basis of what's in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
my_val = 3;

my_var = my_val === 1 ?
    2 : my_val === 3 || my_val === 4 ?
    5 : 0;
```

Or change the value of the variable *after* declaration:

```js
my_val = 3;

let my_var;
switch(my_val) {
    case 1: my_val = 2;
    case 3: case 4: my_val = 5;
    default: my_val = 0;
};
```

Comment: The last one works, but the idea is not to write over and over the name of the variable every time I want to add a new case-value pair